# popup content box on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css

I am not a code expert but am looking for some advise on how the popup images on `mouse over` were created on [St. Andrews Golf Art](http://www.standrewsgolfart.com/browse/Tournaments_2_0_0_na_c.html).

On `mouse over` of the images a box appears with the image and a separate link button.

I am looking to do something similar, preferably with a plugin of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in different ways. One option is to use the overflow property as seen [here](http://cssglobe.com/lab/overflow_thumbs/)
Alternatively, there is this [jquery plugin](http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery) that does the preview thing you want.

That should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I like the overflow example because the image does not move with the mouse (the mouse moves over the image) however, does this display a larger version of the thumb image? What I really wanted was a simple solution to add a button link as well as text and of course a thumbnail image.